# Subquery gives error Invalid argument to function

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, time-series

In MS Access I have table **evo** for variable **vt** per month per country:

**evo:**
**country, mth, vt**
Afghanistan, 1, 20
Afghanistan, 2, 25
Afghanistan, 3, 15
Ukraine, 1, 10
Ukraine, 2, 40
Ukraine, 3, 50

I try to calculate the monthly changes in variable vt. Per country.

```
SELECT b.ctryname_nl, b.mth, b.vt, 
  (SELECT Top 1 a.vt 
   FROM evo a 
   WHERE a.mth > b.mth  and a.ctryname_nl = b.ctryname_nl
   ORDER BY a.ctryname_nl, a.mth) AS Nextvt, 
  Nextvt-vt AS change
FROM evo b
```

Why does Access give the error Invalid argument to function ?

Comment: If you consider `SELECT * FROM evo b` it becomes obvious that `Nextvt` is not in scope (if you assumed left-to-right attribute creation order then you were mistaken). See @Gordon Linoff's answer where he uses a subquery to create an additional level of scope so that `SELECT Nextvt from e` is now possible.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to use a column alias in an expression in the same `SELECT`.

Just use a subquery:

```
SELECT e.*, (Nextvt - vt) AS change
FROM (SELECT b.ctryname_nl, b.mth, b.vt, 
             (SELECT Top 1 a.vt 
              FROM evo as a 
              WHERE a.mth > b.mth  and a.ctryname_nl = b.ctryname_nl
              ORDER BY a.ctryname_nl, a.mth
             ) AS Nextvt
      FROM evo as b
     ) e;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem (or rather an additional problem) is this:

`WHERE a.mth > b.mth  and a.ctryname_nl = b.ctryname_nl`

`b` is not defined within your subquery.

A subquery has the be a valid query in itself. Whatever is within the () has to work as an independent query; that's a good way to troubleshoot subqueries.